# cannot access controls in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I am working on an ASP.NET VB.NET Web Application. I inherited a bunch of forms from another application we have in house. I'm running into a very strange problem when working on the Login page.

This is an abbreviated version of my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
  <table> 
    <tr> 
      <td>
          <span id="Span1" runat="Server" style="Color: Red"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
         <LayoutTemplate>
           <table>
           <tr>
             <td> 
                <span id="Span1" runat="Server" style="Color: Red"></span>
             </td>
           </tr>
           </table>
          </LayoutTemplate>
       </asp:login>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</asp:Content>
```

I have a `<span id="span1">` that is located inside my web form, within the `Content` part of the page. I can easily access this in my CodeBehind, and do whatever I want to do with it. However, if i move that span and put it inside the `<asp:login>` part of the page, it doesn't seem to recognize it, it won't let me access it in code behind, it gives me a squiggly blue line and says

> span1 is not declared. It may inaccessible due to protection level

This bit is from the top of the webform in designer

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" %>
```

This bit is from the Login.aspx.vb page

```
Partial Class _Default
```

Just to say it again, `id="span1"` works perfectly fine where it is shown in the code above, but when I move it inside the  I cannot reference it anymore. Since I'm talking about this issue, for that matter I cannot add any new controls inside  because I am not able to reference any other controls in vb.net. (this form was pretty much copied from another project, everything works properly I'm just not sure why I'm having this strange issue)

I noticed that a lot of people have similar issues, but in my case I'm working with `<asp:login>` and I'm really not sure how it's affecting my controls.

EDIT: `<span id="Span1" runat="Server" style="Color: Red"></span>`

Comment: I think the problem is due to the naming container.  When you move it inside the template, it becomes a child of the `Login1` control and will be removed from the designer file.  Maybe you could try `Login1.FindControl("span1")` in your code-behind instead

Comment: @freefaller I can because i have runat="server" please see edit, that's exactly how it looks. I use it to set .innerHtml text value to it

Comment: then please don't be surprised if we spot problems if you don't show us what you actually have. Please re-read my edited comment which was the primary reason I wrote it

Comment: @freefaller I apologize. This doesn't work as well. Intellisense does pick it up and I also get a squiggly line when I do something like this: Login1.FindControl("span1").InnerHtml="hello". The asp:login has other controls such as textboxes and buttons and there is no need to reference it by prefacing it with Login1.FindControl. It is simply referenced by the control name only

Comment: `.FindControl` returns an object, you need to box it to the correct type before you can call any properties/methods on it.  Something like `CType(Logon1.FindControl("span1"), HtmlGenericControl).InnerHtml = "hello"`

Comment: @freefaller okay this seems to work. Thanks a bunch. please post as answer

Comment: done as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments, and as requested by the OP...

You're hitting a problem with the naming container.

When the `<span runat="server">` is outside of the `<asp:Login><LayoutTemplate>` it exists as an object within the page, which you can reference directly.

As soon as it's moved within that `<LayoutTemplate>` it becomes a child of the `<asp:Login>` control instead.

So to access the control, you can use the following...

```
CType(Logon1.FindControl("span1"), HtmlGenericControl).InnerHtml = "hello"
```

The `FindControl` will bring back an object, but it needs to be "boxed" into the correct type before you can access the `InnerHtml` property

Answer (score 2):

You need to use FindControl on the Login1 Control

```
HtmlGenericControl hgc = Login1.FindControl("Span1") as HtmlGenericControl;
hgc.InnerText = "Span Found";
```

VB

```
Dim hgc As HtmlGenericControl = CType(Login1.FindControl("Span1"),HtmlGenericControl)
hgc.InnerText = "Span Found"
```

Answer (score 1):

to access a control on server side, you must include the "runat='server'" attribute on a tag. That's what tells .NET that any given control is supposed to be worked with on the server side as well as the front-end.

Do note that it will change the ID produced in the rendered HTML

```
<span id="span1" runat="server"></span>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for missing that tidbit but I do have have it runat="server" please see edit. I wasn't entirely copying/pasting code, I type it myself.